# Do I need to operate StateFlow in a coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have read the [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows), I know the Flow need to operate in coroutine, such as Code A.

`StateFlow` inherited from `Flow`, I think I should operate `StateFlow` in a coroutine.

The Code B is from the sample [project](https://github.com/android/compose-samples).

It seems that `fun openDrawer()` operate `MutableStateFlow` directly without in a suspend function, why?

**Code A**

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { // flow builder
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) // pretend we are doing something useful here
        emit(i) // emit next value
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    // Launch a concurrent coroutine to check if the main thread is blocked
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }
    // Collect the flow
    simple().collect { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _drawerShouldBeOpened = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val drawerShouldBeOpened: StateFlow<Boolean> = _drawerShouldBeOpened

    fun openDrawer() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = true
    }
    fun resetOpenDrawerAction() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because writing to the `value` fields doesn't require the `suspend` context. So it's setter is not `suspend`.

But to actually subscribe on the `value` updates, you need the `suspend` context, since `collect` method is `suspend`.

See the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow) for more examples.